# Clone and replace itself with the new added element and its cloned content

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to do the following;

> (1) Clone the element.
>
> (2) Create a new element and concat with the cloned element.
>
> (3) Replace the cloned element with the new one.

```js
var clonedElement = $('.container input#input_text').clone();
    
$(".container input#input_text").replaceWith('<div class="custom-container"><p class="custom-text">Some Text</p>' + clonedElement + '</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<!-- Some auto generated element -->
<!-- Some auto generated element -->
<form>
<!-- Some auto generated element -->
<input id="input_text" />
<!-- Some auto generated element -->
</form>
<!-- Some auto generated element -->
<!-- Some auto generated element -->
</div>
```

The cloned doesn't convert back to its original element, it's just object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `append` the cloned element to your new `div` and then replace the contents of the element with that:

```js
var clonedElement = $('.container input#input_text').clone();

$(".container input#input_text")
    .replaceWith($('<div class="custom-container"><p class="custom-text">Some Text</p></div>')
                     .append(clonedElement));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Some auto generated element -->
  <!-- Some auto generated element -->
  <form>
    <!-- Some auto generated element -->
    <input id="input_text" />
    <!-- Some auto generated element -->
  </form>
  <!-- Some auto generated element -->
  <!-- Some auto generated element -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you use string concatenation on an element, you get the string `"[object HTMLElement]"` for it.

You could use [`wrap`](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/) with the `div` markup, then `before` to add the paragraph:

```js
var clonedElement = $('.container input#input_text').clone();

$(".container input#input_text")
    .wrap("<div class=custom-container></div>")
    .before('<p class="custom-text">Some Text</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<!-- Some auto generated element -->
<!-- Some auto generated element -->
<form>
<!-- Some auto generated element -->
<input id="input_text" />
<!-- Some auto generated element -->
</form>
<!-- Some auto generated element -->
<!-- Some auto generated element -->
</div>
```